# Updating a Referenced Library Within Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

this is probably a stupid question but I can't see anything for the life of me.

Basically I am using Android Studio 0.5.3 and I have imported my projects and all referenced libraries into Android Studio.

This seems to have imported the code for each library into my project and the libraries are working. However, I need to make a change to one of them so I opened up the library in a separate Android Studio window and made the changes.

However, when I go back to Android Studio with my main project the code within the library hasn't updated. I've tried doing a gradle sync but no luck.

So basic question, how do I modify my library and have those changes automatically appear in my main project which references the changed library.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Can you be a lot more specific about what's going on?